# HighChart how set dataLabel position dynamically in formatter base on its value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try drawing a polar chart by 'HighChart' that each series have 2 data category between 0 to 100 that have  overlap on other.
My problem is when data value is greater than 90, dataLabel of 2 category have overlap.
I want set dataLabel position dynamically by formatter function.
All my try to do this was failed.
Is there solution to solve this problem?

In below is my simplified code. And in this [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/M_i_T/s4u04nz6/)  you can see result and edit it

---

```
var chart;
var options={
    chart:
    {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        polar: true
    },
    xAxis:
    {
        categories: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
    },
    yAxis:
    {
        gridLineWidth: 0,                           
        labels:
        {                       
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    colors: ['#F47414', '#A8CBFF'],
    plotOptions:
    {
        column:
        {
            grouping: false,
            shadow: false
        },
        series:
        {
            dataLabels:
            {
                enabled: true   /// for use My solution, comment this line
                /* ------------------------------------------------------------
                /// My solution is using formatter to set y align based on value. But I don't know why this don't work.
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function ()
                {
                    if (this.y>=90 && this.y<100)
                    {
                        console.log(this.series.options.dataLabels.y);
                        this.series.options.dataLabels.y =+ 20;
                    }
                }
                ---------------------------------------------------------------*/
            }
        }
    },
    series:
    [
        {name: 'GoalPerecent', data:[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]},
        {name: 'ActualPerecent', data:[95, 20, 23, 45, 98, 10, 35, 73, 33, 85, 64, 10]}
    ]
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

---

Comment: Please include what your program is currently doing; what kind of errors you are receiving.  You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It reads 'KPI' of 'Percent of goal & actual reached' from CSV file and insert into 'freq' table. then show this data in 'Wind Rose' chart.

Comment: Problem is not error reading from 'CSV' file. Rather problem is overlapping dataLabel (causing  dataLabel would be unreadable) when value is close together

Comment: If you could set up a JSFiddle with sample data that demonstrates the problem then it would be easier for someone to help you!

Comment: upvoted for adding the jsFiddle.

Comment: You can evaluate this examples - http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/6/